# Single SQL query with input tvp parameter when tvp doesn't contain any row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

Anyone knows a kind of this trick

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [pr_GetFinDoc]
    @id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT f.*
    FROM [dbo].[FinDocument] f     --id column is primary key
    WHERE @id is null or f.id = @id
END
```

So, the `procedure` above returns either single `FinDoc` or all `FinDocs`. It depends on whether the `id` was sent or not.

Just a **single** query.

So i need something like that but for `tvp` parameter.

It's my `tvp` parameter - just array of `uniqueidentifier` values

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[GuidList] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

And my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [pr_GetFinDoc]
    @id_list [dbo].[GuidList] READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @id_list)
        BEGIN
            SELECT f.*
            FROM
            @id_list filter 
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[FinDocument] f 
                    ON f.id = filter.Id
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT f.*
            FROM [dbo].[FinDocument] f
        END
END
```

Is there a way to change the code of `SP` with `tvp input parameter` to single query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IN` instead.  This gives you the flexibility to use more complex logic:

```
select f.*
from FinDocument f
where f.id in (select id from @id_list) or
      not exists (select 1 from @id_list);
```

Note that these methods (and yours) are not necessarily efficient.  The `if` logic will *probably* compile using an index on `id`.  Often if the queries are complex, it is better to either force a re-compile or use dynamic SQL (and force a re-compile) because of SQL Server compiles queries the first time the stored procedure is invoked.  And the query plan may not be optimal for all parameter choices.

Comment: thanks for additional info about query plan and the efficiency of the query